# ReduxToolikt entity adapter question: how do i define the selectId type for update?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, createentityadapter

I am learning how to use createEntityAdapter in a working example and I can't resolve the `selectId` for Update functions correctly.

Working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/createentityadapter-demo-forked-5rvl4

The entityAdapter is initialised as:

```
const entityAdapter = createEntityAdapter<Book>({
  selectId: (book) => book.bookId,
  sortComparer: (a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title)
});
```

Adding values works ok:

```
const stateOne = entityAdapter.addOne(initialState, {
  bookId: 1,
  title: "hello"
});

const stateTwo = entityAdapter.addMany(stateOne, [
  { bookId: 2, title: "two" },
  { bookId: 3, title: "three" },
  { bookId: 4, title: "four" }
]);
```

However updateOne gives type error on the bookId:

```
const stateThree = entityAdapter.updateOne(stateTwo, {
  bookId: 3,
   changes: {
     title: "three - change"
   }
});
```

TS error:

> (property) bookId: number
> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 2, '(state: EntityState, update: Update): EntityState', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '{ bookId: number; changes: { title: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Update'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'bookId' does not exist in type 'Update'.
> Overload 2 of 2, '(state: EntityState, update: { payload: Update; type: string; }): EntityState', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '{ bookId: number; changes: { title: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ payload: Update; type: string; }'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'bookId' does not exist in type '{ payload: Update; type: string; }'.ts(2769)

Why am I seeing this error when I have explicitly defined `bookId` as my select Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `update*` methods, the action payload must be an object that has fields exactly named `id` and `changes`, regardless of what the actual ID field is in your data types.  So, this should work correctly:

```js
const stateThree = entityAdapter.updateOne(stateTwo, {
  id: 3,
   changes: {
     title: "three - change"
   }
});
```